# Search multiple words using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do a search for employee using linq.
I want to be albe to search for multible search words(firstname lastname)
I've found some that can do this if I only search in one DB table, but my problem is that I'm seaching in in some joined tables.

An example below

```
    list<employee> list = from(e in dbContext.getTable<employee>
    join dbContext.GetTable<job>() on e.jobi equeals j.id
    where e.firstname.contains(keywords) || j.title.contains(keywords))
    select e).toList()
```

I've would like to search for "Mark developer" and get all persons that are named mark that has a job titel developer.

Any ideers

Answer (score 1):

replace your OR condition `||` with AND condition `&&` to retrieve records only matching both title and name (with `||` you're going to fetch every records which satisfies the name OR the title, which is not what you want).

assuming that `keywords` is a `string` like

```
string keywords = "Mark Developer"; // "<name> <title>"
```

your query should work if modified like this

```
list<employee> list = from(e in dbContext.getTable<employee>
    join dbContext.GetTable<job>() on e.jobi equeals j.id
    where (e.firstname.contains(keywords.split(' ')[0]) && (j.title.contains(keywords.split(' ')[1])))
    select e).toList()
```

if upper/lower/mixed case is an issue, you might want something like

```
list<employee> list = from(e in dbContext.getTable<employee>
    join dbContext.GetTable<job>() on e.jobi equeals j.id
    where (e.firstname.ToLower().contains(keywords.split(' ')[0].ToLower()) && (j.title.ToLower().contains(keywords.split(' ')[1].ToLower())))
    select e).toList()
```

Comment: the problem is actually more how to spit the keywords. If a search for "Mark developer" I don't get any result because the title don't contain both words

Comment: still wouldn't work since there's no one named "mark developer" with the title "mark developer"

Comment: ah now i see. i'm updating my answer assuming you will **always** search for something like "<name> <title>"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should split the keywords into an array

```
 var kwords = keywords.Split(' ');
```

then

```
where (kwords.Contains(e.firstname) || kwords.Contains(j.title))
```

would probably work

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way around. Check if keywords contains the name/title

```
var keys = keywords = keywords.Split(' ');     
list<employee> list = from(e in dbContext.getTable<employee>
        join dbContext.GetTable<job>() on e.jobi equeals j.id
        where keys.Contains(e.firstname) || keys.contains(j.title)
        select e).toList();
```

**EDIT**
if you are looking to also handle people with more than one first name then:

```
var keys = keywords = keywords.Split(' ');     
list<employee> list = from(e in dbContext.getTable<employee>
        join dbContext.GetTable<job>() on e.jobi equeals j.id
        where keys.Any(k=>e.firstname.Contains(k)) 
              || keys.Any(k=> j.title.Contains(k))
        select e).toList();
```

however I don't feel confident that, that can be translated to SQL but since you haven't tagged your question with either linq-2-sql or EF that might not be a problem (though from your code it would seem that an EF tag is probably missing)

**EDIT**
If you are looking to be able to build the query dynamically (which your comments suggest) I woulld suggest that you have a look at [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Comment: That way I must type the precise word to get result
keyword = mark name in DB mark david
Mark don't contain mark david

Comment: @Birger you mean people with two first names?

Comment: yes.. or a titel name IT developer and you only search developer

Comment: i'm using linq 2 sql.. It don't seem to translate to sql

Answer (score -1):

perfect solution

http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/simple-string-keyword-search-using-extensionmethods-and-linq/